# A 'simultaneous firing' problem on Elementary Probability

Tags: probability

I am reading Khinchin's book "An Elementary Introduction to Theory of Probability". There is a problem on chapter 1, section 3, page 9 as stated below.

> One marksman has 80% as his average of target hits and another (under the same firing conditions) has 70%. Find the probability of destroying the target if both marksman shoot at it **simultaneously**. The target is assumed to be destroyed if at least one of the two bullets hits it.

The answers he further reveals is 94%.
What irritates me is the use of the word 'simultaneously'. Khinchin seems to have accounted one trial as - first shot, check, second shot, check. Acc to me , the marksmen have both taken the shots regardless of it being destroyed by either one. Later, the result is exposed to us. Why am I wrong to believe the probability to be 80%, that is the greater of the two?

Comment: Because $80$ percent is simply the probability that the first marksman hits the target; that answer ignores any possibility that the first marksman misses and the second marksman hits. When all four possibilities are accounted for—hit/hit, hit/miss, miss/hit, miss/miss—the probability is seen to be $94$ percent. ¶ It's actually immaterial that the shots are actually simultaneous. What matters is that (a) both marskmen shoot at the target, (b) their success or failure are independent of each other, and (c) we want the probability of at least one success out of the two shots.

Comment: P.S. Specifically, hit/hit gets $0.8 \times 0.7 = 0.56$, hit/miss gets $0.8 \times 0.3 = 0.24$, miss/hit gets $0.2 \times 0.7 = 0.14$, and miss/miss gets $0.2 \times 0.3 = 0.06$.

Comment: Compare to a far simpler situation... you flip two fair coins.  (*In sequence, simultaneously, identical coins or different coins, doesn't matter*).  What is the probability of at least one head?  Even with the simultaneous tossing of the coins, are you equally of the opinion that this should also be 50% chance?  What is it about the original problem and this problem that you feel are different that your analysis of the problem should be different?

Comment: The only reason for stating "simultaneously" is so you don't have to worry about whether the second shooter bothers to take a shot if the first shooter has already destroyed the target.  It doesn't change the final answer, but it might change how you calculate it.

Comment: I am trying to grasp this idea of probability lately. It uptil now, seems to be a very wishful metric. I was confused because there is an apparent change in experiment on simultaneous execution. What is the criteria of two hits if the target is destroyed already? How would we know whom missed? I believed (wrongfully so) that the theory of probability is applicable to situations where individual (elementary) events play out as independent as alone. Like flipping of two coins as two different places, not on one-another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not the shots are taken sequentially or simultaneously is irrelevant to the resulting probability.  The **only** thing that matters in regard to the probability of the target having been destroyed, is that **both** marksmen take a shot at the target irrespective of the outcome of the other's shot.  Whether or not the individual probabilities of each marksman hitting the target is a faithful model for the joint probability of either marksman hitting the target, is a separate matter.

The purpose of this exercise is to understand the probability of complementary events and independent events.  The statement of the problem implicitly assumes (but does not state) that the outcome of either marksman's shot does not impact the outcome of the other's shot.  This assumption is implied through the statement that the shots are taken simultaneously, but simultaneity is not a requirement for the independence of outcomes, because the target can be destroyed at most once:  if the shots are taken sequentially and the first marksman hits it, then the destruction of the target does not affect the second marksman's shot because the event of interest has already been observed.  Furthermore, if the first marksman misses, then the target is still intact and the second marksman's shot (ideally) should be no different than had the first marksman not taken a shot.

Of course, in the real world, this may not be a valid assumption, but it is no more or less valid than assuming that even if the shots were taken simultaneously, then their outcomes are independent.  For the purposes of solving the problem and understanding the underlying mathematical concepts, it is reasonable to impose the independence assumption on our model for the outcome of the two shots.

The easiest way to conceptualize the solution under this assumption is to then consider the complementary event; i.e., what is the probability that *both* marksmen miss?  Because of independence this is simply the product of the individual probabilities that each miss; i.e., it is
$$(1-0.8)(1-0.7) = (0.2)(0.3) = 0.06.$$

Then the desired probability is simply $1 - 0.06 = 0.94$.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, it holistically captures all concerning points. Thank you.

It is just this method of evaluation that I concord with (when they both miss). Khinchin must have presented this example to emphasize on the union of events concept. This just happens because the trials get squeezed together.

I will admit, I am being pedantic here, on the validity of the model.